# SAS: How to vertically join multiple datasets where a variable is numeric in one dataset and character in the other

Tags: sas, data-analysis, sas-macro

This is complicated a little because we're using a pipeline with a filelist to compile the data, so there are 50+ datasets coming in. I need to combine many, many datasets vertically, but var2 is numeric in some and character in others. Var1 is not important, so we can drop it, but when I try to drop it in the data step, it is throwing an error because of the differing data types. More details below.

Here's what I want to do at it's most basic...

> data in1;
> input var1 $ var2
> datalines;
> a 1
> b 2
> ;
>
> data in2;
> input var1 $ var2 $
> datalines;
> a 1a
> b 2b
> ;
>
> data newdd;
> set in1 in2;
> run;

Is it possible to combine these datasets in the "data newdd" step without changing the inputs? Is there a way to drop var2 in this data step in a way that will still let it merge var1 and not throw an error? Or better yet, can I make var2 read in as character in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

To drop var2 use a data set option.

```
data newdd;
set in1(drop=var2) in2(drop=var2);
run;
```

To combine and ensure it's the same:

```
data newdd;
set in1 (in=t1 rename=var2=_var2) in2(in=t2 );
if t1 then var2 = put(_var2, 8. -l);
run;
```

Long answer - you need to fix how you read in the files - all 50 from source so they're consistent. You can have SAS generate the correct types/INPUT statement if you have a master list of variables and type/length/format/informat, type at minimum.

Comment: Thank you. You did answer the question I asked but I realize I oversimplified it. The data being combined is generated by a filelist. The pipeline generates the filelist, proc sql generates a macro that iterates through the filelist, and then a data statement calls the macro. So the set statement is actually "set &filelist". This has worked well when the variable types are the same, but now that I'm running into instances where they're different, using the (drop=) option hasn't worked.

Comment: What is the original source of the 50 files? How were they imported? That stage needs to be fixed.